# How to load only visible images in react

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am working on gallery related react web application.I am displaying 100 thumbnails in single page for this i have to call 100 api's at a time.But on screen window right now only 10 thumbnails are there so i have to call only 10 api's, So is there any way to restrict api calls based on screen visibility.

Comment: Should i ask why do u fetch 100 thumbnails if there only 10 visible at begin? Why dont u fetch only 20 and fetch the next one after scrolling? Back to ur question: you should google for IntersectionObserver

Comment: pagination option is there but it is not possible as per our feature or server requirements. Yeah i heard intersectionObserver, is there any npm library available to resolve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

For images, you could use this

```
<img src="image.jpg" loading="lazy">
```

You can read more about it here:
https://betterprogramming.pub/5-ways-to-lazy-load-react-components-4ffebf1c2088